# uploading flie to FastAPI endpoint using curl - 307 Temporary Redirect

Tags: python, http, curl, fastapi

I have a fastAPI endpoint that recieves a file and saves it to disk as follows:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
import shutil

app = FastAPI()

@app.post('/upload')
async def upload_file(file: UploadFile=File(...)):
    with open(file.filename, "wb") as buffer:
        shutil.copyfileobj(file.file, buffer)

    return {
        "filename": file.filename,
    }
```

This works as expected when I upload a file through the docs interface at `http://localhost:8000/docs`
I am able to select a file and it successfully uploads.

However, attempting the same with curl fail:

```sh
curl -X POST localhost:8000/upload -F file=@photo.png
```

the curl command returns nothing and on the server side a `307 Temporary Redirect` is logged.

I am not sure what I am missing here

Comment: are you executing curl from the same local machine from where you have ran `http://localhost:8000/docs` ? you curl looks fine. if you try with complete address `curl -X 'POST' 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload' -F 'file=@photo.png', what you get? also try to put headers in curl if that is making request to redirect.

Comment: Yes everything is run from my local machine. Changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 in the curl command fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: @simpleApp you may want to make an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Thank you! :) added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some scenario/setup where `FastAPI` redirect the request, use the curl with full dns/ip address.

something like this :

```
curl -X 'POST' '127.0.0.1:8000/upload' -F 'file=@photo.png
```

or can add headers(-H) too based on the application that is built.

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'file=@photo.png;type=application/json'
```